# Disponibilizar botões dinamicamente

Tags: c#

inserir a descrição da imagem aquiGostaria de saber como posso através de uma textbox inserir um valor numérico, e com este valor `x` tornar visível `x` botões de `y`.

> ex. se eu digitar 3 na textbox, o botão 1, 2 e 3 ficarão visíveis

Estou desenvolvendo um form no qual salvo em uma datatable sql, as possíveis datas e quantidade de horários por cada data (ou seja se definir 3, todas essas datas terão 3 horários). Em outro form vou agendar os eventos, e queria que ficasse disponíveis as datas da tabela e os horários, a medida que fosse cadastrando os eventos, os mesmos iriam aparecer como ocupados ou livres. Tipo marcação de assento em aviões.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado pela ajuda, com sua ajuda e pesquisas consegui o resultado desejado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

namespace teste3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int Dias;
        int Horarios;

```
    private Button[][] botoes = new Button[3][];
    private GroupBox[] grupo = new GroupBox[3];

    int quantidade;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        botoes[0] = new Button[5] { btnA1, btnA2, btnA3, btnA4, btnA5 };
        botoes[1] = new Button[5] { btnB1, btnB2, btnB3, btnB4, btnB5 };
        botoes[2] = new Button[5] { btnC1, btnC2, btnC3, btnC4, btnC5 };

        grupo = new GroupBox[] { group_1, group_2, group_3 };
    }

    private void btn_Verificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dias = int.Parse(text_Dias.Text);
        Horarios = int.Parse(text_Bancas.Text);
        EscondeBotoes();

        // Display the array elements:
        for (int i = 0; i < Dias; i++)
        {
            grupo[i].Visible = true;

            for (int j = 0; j < Horarios; j++)
            {
                botoes[i][j].Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void EscondeBotoes()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            grupo[i].Visible = false;

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                botoes[i][j].Visible = false;
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Se pretende mostrar `x` `TextBox`, consoante um valor, pode criar um array para as guardar e atribuir o `Visible` correto para cada uma através de um laço/ciclo. Desta forma fica um pouco mais flexível e fácil de expandir para mais elementos.

Exemplo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private TextBox[] botoes; //array de textboxes

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //colocar no array as textboxes que quer e pela ordem certa
        botoes = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 };
    }

    //este método mostra a quantidade de textboxes correspondente ao parametro passado
    private void Mostrar(int quantidade)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < botoes.Length; ++i)
        {
            botoes[i].Visible = (i < quantidade) ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

Assim para o que tinha dito

> se eu digitar 3 na textbox, o botão 1, 2 e 3 ficarão visíveis

Bastaria chamar o método com esse valor: `Mostrar(3);`.

Note que a mesma lógica é aplicável a `Button` ou qualquer outro elemento de formulário que dê jeito.

Comment: Não teria como fazer um array dos botões pra habilitar eles e depois mudar o texto de cada e o valor q ele passa ao ser clicado? Vou usar os botões como os assentos dos marcadores de assento das cia areas

Comment: @i_melo O array dos botões seria exatamente igual ao dos textboxes. Mudar o valor quando clica também da perfeitamente. Agora não estou a visualizar exatamente o que está a tentar fazer em relação aos assentos e isso.

Comment: Tenho uma db em sql que guarda varias datas pra agendamento de defesa de monografia. Uma form irá verificar essas datas e pra cada data irá me informar os horários vagos. Para que eu possa agendar em outra db essas bancas. Dai os botões.  Criei groupbox com 5 botões pra cada data disponível q estão invisiveis por padrão. Se houver 2 datas, ele libera apenas 2 groupbox. Os botões serão os horarios disponiveis, horários já agendados irão exibir um código no botão pra avisar q ele está indisponível. Ao selecionar um botão disponivel ele preenche uma textbox com o horario pra salvar na db.

Comment: @i_melo Coloque um print do que tem para que seja visualmente mais fácil de acompanhar. Mas se eu percebi corretamente, o melhor será ter uma lista de elementos de uma classe feita por si que indicam se determinado horário está disponível ou não. Depois através de um laço/ciclo escondem ou mostram no array de textboxes. Se já tem classes para isso convêm indicar também.

Comment: Esse é o form. Ele irá buscar os dados de uma db, esconderá os groupbox. Pra cada dia disponível ele libera um groupbox. Na mesma db, está a quantidade de horários por dia. Então somente será mostrado a quantidade de horarios especificados pra cada dia. Ao clicar no botão ele salva em outra db, todos os dados recuperados da outra db, e acrescenta data e horário. Quando abrir esse form novamente naquele dia e naquele horario o botão correspondente terá como label o código da apresentaçao. Daí saberei que aquele horário está indisponivel. Terei de escolher outro horário através de outro botão.

Comment: @i_melo Coloque o código que está utilizar para ir buscar horários disponíveis e indisponíveis, que será onde precisa de incorporar o código que eu dei na resposta.